# Printing array vs. integer as hex

Tags: c++, hex

I am using an API that uses a struct to represent an array (and allows filling up that array while accessing the struct).

If data is a struct object, and direction is a uint32_t, run the following:

```
printf("0x%08X", data->magic);
```

I get the value: 0xAAAABEEF

while printing the array directly as such:

```
printf("0x");
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  printf("%02X", payload[i]);
}
```

I get the value: 0xEFBEAAAA

the struct definition goes like this:

```
struct Data {
  uint32_t magic;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I believe the data variable is declared something like this:

```
// Declared and initialized somewhat like this:
uint8_t payload[kMaxSize];
Data* data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(payload);
data->magic = 0xAAAABEEF;
```

I am curious why the printf does not return the same value. Is it because the machine is storing the data as LSB (least significant byte)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct.  In a [little-endian processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) (eg: **x86**), the least significant byte is stored first in memory.  So the number `0xAAAABEEF` will be stored as four bytes in memory: `{0xEF, 0xBE, 0xAA, 0xAA}`

When your program looks at those four bytes in memory, the way the data is interpreted - its *type* - determines how it looks.  If `{0xEF, 0xBE, 0xAA, 0xAA}` is interpreted as individual bytes, you get "EF BE AA AA".  But if it's interpreted as a `uint32_t`, then the computer knows to reverse the order and display it as "0xAAAABEEF".

Comment: Thank you very much! Apologies if it was a trivial question; I was having deep doubts about my understanding - thank you for the clear explanation.